# How to combine this into one line?

Tags: php

Sorry, im a php newbie, is it possible do the things in iWantThisInOneLineOnly() only with one line?

i dont even know what keywords to search with

```
<?php
    class combine {

        $json = '{"Key":"Value"}';
        $key = "Key";

        function iWantThisInOneLineOnly() {
            $key = $this->key;
            return json_decode($this->json)->$key;
            //Something like json_decode($this->json)->($this->key); ??
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Does your code in the comment work? `json_decode($this->json)->($this->key);`

Comment: @luekbaja no, it doesn't work, or im already using it XD it said "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly braces instead:

```
return json_decode($this->json)->{$this->key};
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/C2ctv**

Comment: oh thanks! its very confused that its not using normal bracket